# Why ItemTouchHelper.startSwipe not working?

Tags: android, swipe, itemtouchhelper

Is there a working example of using ItemTouchHelper.startSwipe ?
I found documentation with example here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper#startSwipe(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
But I could not make it working.

Also there is the same old question without answers: [ItemTouchHelper startSwipe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439816/itemtouchhelper-startswipe-not-working)